# how to configure qmake in linux(ubuntu) to use libqt4-gui in standard location like /usr/lib?

Tags: qt, qmake

When you try to install QtSDK, it will install in /opt/QtSDK(with root access) or some place that you want. Then when you you qmake with qtcreator to create you application it will use libqtgui.so from that place you install QtSDK. For example after using **ldd** command to detect dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `qmake` mkspecs for the your platform.  I think you need to change `QMAKE_INCDIR_QT` and `QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT` in `linux.conf` in .../mkspecs/common.

Comment: When I add this line to .pro file : QMAKKE_LIBDIR_QT = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu(where is standard location for qt). But the compiler error like this : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore

Comment: That's not a standard Linux location for Qt, `/usr/lib` is the usual one.  Are you sure the Qt libraries are in that directory?

Comment: yes, I'm sure, because when use synaptic to install Qt, then use this location and this location exist in gcc search path `gcc -print-serach-dirs`.

Comment: I'm stil not convinced.  Open a file browser, go to that dir and _look_ at the Qt libs, that's the only way to be sure.

Comment: yes, I examined with file browser and I was correct. The default location for Qt library is /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.

Comment: You mentioned `libqt4-gui`, in the title.  Do the files named in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` follow that pattern, or `libQtGui`, `libQtCore`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way :

The gcc has options with -rpath name for searching so file when it begins to start and qmake use QMAKE_RPATH for describing this. Therefore 
1. QMAKE_RPATH must be set in QTDIR/.../gcc/mkspecs/qtconfig.pri file.
2. Add this line to .pro file QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.

Now, you have an executable with standard place.

Answer (score 0):

The prefered path to the dynamic libraries can be passed to the linker within the option `rpath`. To make qmake putting that option into the Makefile, add the following line to your `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += /prefered/path/to/lib/
```

Note: `QMAKE_RPATH` seems not to work anymore: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-8110